# Backbone.js when I create a model and I want to delete now

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

I have express.js in server side with mongodb, and brunch with chaplin.js on front, my problem is when I create a model, it's appear in the list of model, but I can't delete it because the method isNew() return true.

I think is a problem with the server side, isn't it ?

This is the code

**comment_view.coffee**

```
View = require 'views/base/view'
template = require 'views/templates/comment'
mediator = require 'mediator'

module.exports = class CommentView extends View
  template: template
  autoRender: true
  container: '.list-comment'
  tagName: 'li'

  initialize: ->
    @delegate 'click', '.icon-remove', @remove_one

  remove_one: ->
    @model.destroy()
    @remove()
```

**server.js**

```
app.delete('/api/comments/:id',function(req, res) {
  CommentsEventModel.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, comments) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    res.send(200);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is your issue (a) that you cannot 'delete' model created client side, but not yet persisted to the server, or (b) a model that is pulled down from the server is registering as `IsNew()` so calls to `Destroy()` do not result in an Ajax call to your sever (and thus the model isn't deleted from Mongo) ?

Answer (score 1):

If `model.isNew()` returns `true` is because `model.id` is `null`.

Try to check how your server responses to the `CREATE` verb and if it is responding with a proper JSON format with an `id` field in it.

Comment: I think the CREATE verb is not correct, because I don't return JSON. https://gist.github.com/3775173

Comment: Return a JSON with at least the brand new `id` for this Model.

Comment: Try to name the `id` attribute like `id` instead of `event_id`. At least you want to complicate the things.

Comment: I can do this https://gist.github.com/3775657 because comments return JSON object of the model.